# Obtain commits associated with pipeline run

Tags: git, azure, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml, azure-repos

In the Azure Pipelines Bun/Run view I can see that the current build is associated with the last N commits:
[Last 7 commits](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mr80f.png)

This is much more valuable than the `Build.SourceVersion` pipeline variable for incremental build's sake as I could be able to tell exactly what has changed since the last run.

I've looked at `dev.azure.com/{org}/{project}/_traceability/runview/changes?currentRunId={id}` but don't see the commits in there.

I've also tried to specify `https://dev.azure.com/{org}/{projct}/_apis/build/changes?toBuildId={id}`, but without the previous build ID, it errors.

Is there a way to easily access which changes this pipeline build is running with ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that using the changes API with the same build number as both `fromBuildId` and `toBuildId` does just that.